# ошибка "error": "InvalidParameters: AppleDeliveryError:BAD_REQUEST_TOPIC_DISALLOWED" после отправки уведомление на IOS через fcm в postman

Tags: ios, firebase, postman

есть приложение ios в которое я отправляю push уведомления через fcm в postman. Приложение зарегистрировано в fcm с помощью файла p8, key id, teem id. Уведомления доходят все хорошо. Я создал новое приложение зарегистрировал его с теми же данными в fcm  - получаю токен fcm, отправляю по нему - получаю ошибку "error": "InvalidParameters: AppleDeliveryError:BAD_REQUEST_TOPIC_DISALLOWED". Я пробывал менять файл p8, key id, создавал новое приложение - такая же ошибка в чем может быть дело?